# How can I save a variable which has the same value after an update as before?

Tags: swift, save, app-store, updates

I created an iPhone game in Swift and I want to submit it to the app store. My question: when I create an update for the app how can I make that after the update the "highscore" integer has the same value as before?
Do I need to save the variable into a plist file or something else?

Comment: Yes but will this value be overwritten during an update?

Comment: It will be rewritten when you rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
let highscore: Int = 1

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey:"highscore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```